# Callback in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have made API and trying use it in my jQuery scripts. But having problems with callbacks.
My JavaScript:

```
function findAll() {
    var users;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            users = data;
        }
    });
    return users;
}
```

Help me return received data, please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write a call back function and replace that with success function.
var successCallback = function(result){console.log(result)};
success: successCallback

Comment: You need to place all logic that depends on the result of the request in the callback. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because you are returning `users` synchronously. The value will be `undefined`.

What is happening is this:
 - `var users` is declared and set to `undefined` by the Javascript engine

- the AJAX callback is registered to be called when the `XHR` request resolves
- `var users` (now = `undefined`) is returned
- `users` is assigned the response of the `XHR` request. But alas! It's too late and `undefined` has already been returned!!

This should work:

```
function returnUsers(users) {
    return users;
}

var users = findAll(returnUsers);

function findAll(callback) {
 $.ajax({
    url: "/user",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: callback
 });

}
```

Comment: Yes, thats why I'm asking :)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: This also should not, success function return value, but not findAll

Comment: And value of users is undefined still

Comment: This will not work as you are returning from an anonymous function, not the `findAll()` function, so the data is lost. You need to place all logic which depends on the result of the request *within* the callback

Comment: `This should work` - that does NOT work.

Comment: Updated the response with the new solution

Comment: It's still not going to work. You cannot return anything from an async function. Check the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Comment: Sorry, made a further change